# Protect individual values in std::array while allowing complete overwrite

Tags: c++, immutability, stdarray

I have an array which is global state. This is running in an embedded/microcontroller environment, not a large application where I might be more concerned about global state.

How can I declare the array such that its members cannot be changed, yet I can still update a copy, and yet still completely overwrite the global array when needed?

I'm interested in using an immutable array for this to be able to quickly check if it has changed when it gets returned from a mutation function. That is, if the memory address has changed, then I know it was copied and updated.

If it has been updated, then I want to overwrite the original global array with the updated version.

However, I want to protect the individual values of the array from being accidentally overwritten in main() or in case the global array is otherwise accessed and directly updated. Maybe I'm paranoid, but for the sake of the question let's say this is a valid concern.

The only updates that should be possible should done via copy / address update.

This version works, but the global array can be accessed and directly updated:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

std::array<int, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3}; // global array

std::array<int, 3> const * mutate(std::array<int, 3> const * ptr) {
  // (*ptr)[2] = 9; // I like how this is prevented by const
  // return ptr; // uncomment to test no mutation

  // mutation via copy, retain new array on the heap
  std::array<int, 3> * ret = new std::array<int, 3>;
  std::copy((*ptr).begin(), (*ptr).end(), (*ret).begin());
  (*ret)[0] = 9;
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  std::array<int, 3> const * retPtr = mutate(&arr);

  if (retPtr == &arr) {
    std::cout << "pointers are the same\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "pointers are different\n";
    arr = (*retPtr);
    // do expensive things here with the new state
  }
  delete[] retPtr;

  for (int val : arr) {
    std::cout << val;
    std::cout << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

First I tried declaring the array as `std::array<int, 3> const`. This prevented me from being able to completely overwrite the array.

```
std::array<int, 3> const arr = {1, 2, 3};

...

arr = (*retPtr); // Compilation error: no viable overloaded '='
```

Then I tried declaring it as `std::array<int const, 3>`, but this prevented me from being able to mutate the copy in the mutation function.

```
std::array<int const, 3> arr = {1, 2, 3};

std::array<int const, 3> * mutate(std::array<int const, 3> * ptr) {
  std::array<int const, 3> * ret = new std::array<int const, 3> {0,0,0};
  std::copy((*ptr).begin(), (*ptr).end(), (*ret).begin());

  // Compilation error: cannot assign to return value because function 'operator[]' 
  // returns a const value
  (*ret)[0] = 9; 

  return ret;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: The real answer here is to not expose the array itself as global. Encapsulate it in your own class that exposes the basic features you require (_e.g._ indexing, access via pointer). Those methods would not allow modification of the underlying data, so it's impossible to accidentally overwrite the data (in a valid program). You would then add methods to that class that perform the "replacement" logic, or explicitly request a modifiable array reference, if you must. You define a global instance of your class and use it as if it's an array. This kind of encapsulation is bread-and-butter C++.

Comment: "*How can I declare the array such that its members cannot be changed, ... yet still completely overwrite the global array when needed?*" - you can't. Either the whole array is read-only, or the whole array is writable. There is no in-between. You need to hide the array behind an abstraction to achieve the control you want.

Comment: You allocate with `new` and free with `delete[]`. It's worth noting that the more pointers you use, the more miserable your C++ experience will be. Is it strictly necessary here?

Comment: You also have a peculiar habit of spacing out the pointer type indicator `*` which makes it look like multiplication. It's generally stuck to one of either the type or the variable, there are good cases for both styles, but leaving it "floating" is distracting. That is `const char* x` or `const char *x` but not `const char * x` where it looks like an operator.

Comment: @paddy - I am wondering how expensive is the process of initializing a new object from a class like you described vs. replacing the array. Perhaps there are better or worse ways to do this? Fundamentally, I want to be able to compare the memory addresses of the new and old state object (array or otherwise) to see if any state has changed, and then only do expensive side effects when necessary, ideally on a different thread. The point of this is to run a while(true) loop within main() at very fast speeds allowing the microcontroller to respond to signals at frequencies in the MHz range.

Comment: @tadman I believe `new` and `delete[]` are necessary here to return a pointer from the mutation function so that the memory address may be compared. Checking the memory address is the fastest way I know of to determine if the state object (array or otherwise) has changed. It's my understanding that this is one of the most powerful aspects of working with immutable data.

Comment: What I mean is `new` is paired with `delete`, and `new[]` is paired with `delete[]`.

Comment: "Checking the memory address is the fastest way I know of to determine if the state object...has changed." Is this a copy-on-write structure? If not, that will absolutely not work.

Comment: @fisherwebdev It's not really "initializing a new object". A well-written wrapper interface can be totally transparent (_i.e._ zero runtime overhead), while still enforcing compile-time access rules driven by your design. Your desire to know if a "state has changed" by comparing memory addresses implies that you must actually allocate a new object somewhere. I don't see why you need to do that. You can just as easily set a flag or increment a "change" counter when modifying your state and compare that instead. Consider a double buffer, updating the "change" when you finalize/switch buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using c++20 or greater, this is now doable. A change in [basic life](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#8) has made possible replacing objects so long as the object replaced can be transparently replaced. This limits you to not changing the length of the array or it's element type as these would change the object type. Note that since `std::array` can only be initialized by an initializer list, you would have to list each element in such a list so this gets unwieldy for large arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <memory>

std::array< const int, 3> a{ 1,2,3 };
void mutate()
{
    std::destroy_at(&a);  // call destructor. not needed unless array elements have destructors
    std::construct_at(&a, std::array<const int, 3> {2, 3, 4});
}

int main()
{
    mutate();
    std::cout << a[0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! While I will probably rethink how I am approaching this along the lines suggested by @paddy, I very much appreciate this answer to the actual question I was asking. ✌️

Comment: @fisherwebdev I too very much agree with @paddy's comment but wanted to specifically address your question as the techniques are not generally known and can be useful beyond `std::array`